# best way to zip results from Q.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

What is the best way to zip results from parallel (Q.all) promises call? Simply

```
.spread(function(result1, result2) {return _.zip(result1, result2);})
```

Anything nicer?

Comment: result1 and result2 are both arrays that are the result of `Q.all`? For example `Q.all([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).whateverShouldWork()` should return a Promise over `[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily shorten that to

```
.spread(_.zip)
```